# why 'this' keyword is not working inside shorthand method of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript. I used 'this' as below in javascript

```
let person = {
    name: 'Krishna',
    age: 35,
    sayHello() {
        return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;
     },
     sayHi: () => `Hi ${this.name}`
};

console.log(person.sayHello());
console.log(person.sayHi());
```

sayHello() function is properly getting 'this' as person object. But in shorthand function sayHi(), this is referring to global window object. Here I am calling sayHi() with person object. But not sure why this is not getting referred to window object. Can any one please explain why this in sayHi() is not getting initialized with person object?

Comment: Because you are calling it from a context where the global window is assigned to `this` and the arrow function (lamda) is capturing that passing it on to the call.

Comment: Hint: Don't use arrow functions for an object's methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `sayHello()`, you are leaving the `this` keyword unbound, to be assigned in the function invocation `person.sayHello()`. `this` refers to whatever is left of the dot in the invocation, namely `person`.

In `sayHi()`, you are binding the `this` keyword at the moment `sayHi` is defined. Since the context is not a function invocation but rather an object definition, the value of `this` is unknown and it defaults to the `window` object. Once you bind it in this way, **it cannot be reassigned.**  When you run `person.sayHi()`, `this` refers to `window` and not `person`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the arrow function point to the same object as it did right before the arrow function was assigned (`window`).

If you really want to access the `person` object inside arrow function you have to do that directly by the the object name (`person`):

```js
let person = {
    name: 'Krishna',
    age: 35,
    sayHello() {
        return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.name;
     },
    sayHi: () => `Hi ${person.name}`
};

console.log(person.sayHello());
console.log(person.sayHi());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers
>   to the originating context.

```
{
  sayHi: () =>  // in context,
  sayHello() {
    // needs this to be in context
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sayHi: () => ...` you are bounding `this` to the global context, not to `person`, thus you don't have a `name` property on the scope. [This reading might help you.](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

In `sayHello`, you are returning the resulting string (which is calculating in context of the object (has `this`).

In `sayHi`, you are returning a function to console.log and then calling it where `this` is no longer defined because you're out of context.